# Javascript - Is this method of calling elements bad practice?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the vague title, couldn't figure out how to describe it.

So instead of using getElementBy every time I have...

```
 function tagId(bar) {
        var selectId = document.getElementById(bar);
        return selectId;
 }

 function tagClass(bar) {
        var selectClass = document.getElementsByClassName(bar);
        return selectClass;
 }

tagId('idname').style.background = "blue";
```

It works, but is it conventional to call elements with functions like that instead of just using a variable? Or is it gonna cause bugs later?

Comment: All this does is add a tiny bit of overhead because of the function call, why not just use `getElementById`/`getElementsByClassName` directly? As for any problems/bugs, no you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: ^ that, and no it's not bad practice or going to cause any bugs.

Comment: Nothing will cause bugs by itself. For the most part, bugs are a result of writing code that is not readable or maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Creating shorter helper functions is fairly common because of JS's verbose method names.

One thing to keep in mind is that your `getElementsByClassName` call assumes it will always be called from `document` when it could be called from another element too.

```
function tagClass(context, cls) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
      cls = context;
      context = document;
    }
    return context.getElementsByClassName(cls);
}
```

This version lets you optionally pass a context node to the first argument.

Of course you can always use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` instead of the various other methods. They can take the place of all of the following:

- getElementById
- getElementsByName
- getElementsByTagName
- getElementsByClassName

As well as providing much more fine grained DOM querying capabilities. Basically the same stuff you can do in CSS can be done with the query selector methods.

As noted by [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) in the comment below, an important difference is that `querySelectorAll` does not return a live list (a collection that updates its members as matching elements are added to and removed from the DOM).

Comment: Noting that the *getElementsBy\** methods return live NodeLists, whereas *querySelectorAll* returns a static NodeList. ;-)